# Race Conditions With std::ref and Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to prevent a race condition with a thread that I pass some variables to by std::ref, but not quite sure how to do it.

I've got essentially:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

std::mutex mtx;
float getXData();
float getYData();
void plot(std::vector<float> x, std::vector<float> y);
void calculateMeasurements(bool& currentlyRunning, std::vector<float>& xMeasurements,
                           std::vector<float>& yMeasurements){
  while (true){
     xMeasurements.push_back(getXData());
     yMeasurements.push_back(getYData());
     ...
         if (someCondition){
             currentlyRunning=false;
             xMeasurements.clear();xMeasurements.push_back(0);
             yMeasurements.clear();yMeasurements.push_back(0);
             currentlyRunning=true;
         }
    }

}


int main(){
std::vector<float> xMeasurements;
std::vector<float> yMeasurements;
xMeasurements.push_back(0);
yMeasurements.push_back(0);
bool currentlyRunning{true};
auto thread = std::thread(calculateMeasurements, std::ref(currentlyRunning), 
              std::ref(xMeasurements), std::ref(yMeasurements));
while (true){
  ...
  mtx.lock();
    if(currentlyRunning==true && xMeasurements.size()==yMeasurements.size()){
         plot(xMeasurements,yMeasurements);
         }
    }
  mtx.unlock();
}
```

So essentially what happens is there's one thread in the background pushing back elements to xMeasurements and yMeasurements, that also occasionally resets xMeasurements and yMeasurements to just one element of 0.
The function plot requires that xMeasurements and Ymeasurements have the same size.

I thought that std::mutex::lock makes all the variables between std::mutex::lock and std::mutex::unlock only editable by the thread that calls std::mutex::lock until it unlocks, so here it should prevent the other thread from changing currentlyRunning,xMeasurements & yMeasurements. Howevever occasionally it fails on line          plot(xMeasurements,yMeasurements); because of xMeasurements.size()!=yMeasurements.size() (so plot tries to read it between      xMeasurements.push_back(getXData()); and      yMeasurements.push_back(getYData());, which if I was correct about how mutex works shouldn't happen since it checks they're the same size within the lock) or it fails because either xMeasurements or yMeasurements are empty (which if I was correct about how mutex works shouldn't happen because it checks if currentlyRunning==true within the lock, and they can only be empty when currentlyRunning==false).

How do I correctly prevent another thread from changing the variables passed by reference to it?

Thanks

Comment: A mutex provides mutual exclusion only for the thread(s) that lock it. Putting a lock on the front door does nothing if someone just climbs over the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::mutex::lock **does not protect the variables** between it and std::mutex::unlock. Think of it as **protecting segments of your code** instead. You need to lock and unlock around each time you access and edit global data structures modified by threads. Make sure to lock down when you edit xMeasurements and yMeasurements in your thread method as well. When I program with threads, I generally like to introduce one mutex per global structure that could cause a race condition, but you may be able to do it with one here.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

std::mutex mtx;
float getXData();
float getYData();
void plot(std::vector<float> x, std::vector<float> y);
void calculateMeasurements(bool& currentlyRunning, std::vector<float>& xMeasurements,
                           std::vector<float>& yMeasurements){
  while (true){
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
     xMeasurements.push_back(getXData());
     yMeasurements.push_back(getYData());
     ...
         if (someCondition){
             currentlyRunning=false;
             xMeasurements.clear();xMeasurements.push_back(0);
             yMeasurements.clear();yMeasurements.push_back(0);
             currentlyRunning=true;
         }
    }

}


int main(){
std::vector<float> xMeasurements;
std::vector<float> yMeasurements;
xMeasurements.push_back(0);
yMeasurements.push_back(0);
bool currentlyRunning{true};
auto thread = std::thread(calculateMeasurements, std::ref(currentlyRunning), 
              std::ref(xMeasurements), std::ref(yMeasurements));
while (true){
  ...
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
    if(currentlyRunning==true && xMeasurements.size()==yMeasurements.size()){
         plot(xMeasurements,yMeasurements);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, just to check I understand, essentially what you're saying is that when you call mtx.lock() in one section, any other thread that reaches a mtx.lock() will wait until the first section reaches mtx.unlock()?

Comment: Exactly. It will stall on the mtx.lock() until the original thread calls mtx.unlock(). cplusplus.com describes it as "
A mutex is a lockable object that is designed to signal when critical sections of code need exclusive access, preventing other threads with the same protection from executing concurrently and access the same memory locations." That is to say, it protects the critical sections themselves, not the variables within

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and clear help, I've accepted this answer.

Comment: @JohnCunningham @JohnDoe
Remark: your code is not exception-safe. If a crash would happen in the thread after mutex is locked and before mutex is unlocked - you will have a mutex locked forever. Use [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) for scoped lock.

Comment: @k.v. Thanks for letting me know! I will update the answer to reflect this

Comment: @k.v. Thanks, for the help, though I'm a bit confused on the point. What does it matter if the mutex remains locked if the program crashed anyway?

Also reading your reference for std::lock_guard am I right in thinking it essentially unlocks only once it reaches the end of the while loop in this case?

What if the while loop had more code that took a substantial amount of time to run after the plot function, which you want to unlock before performing?